# Copy of old forum?

Tags: forum

Is there a copy somewhere of the old bitcoin forum?

I would like to read early discussions and banter.

Comment: If you're talking about the forum that used to be at forum.bitcoin.org, then it's the same forum as the one at bitcointalk.org. Are you referring to some other forum?

Comment: The very old SourceForge forum was lost AFAIK, but there weren't many posts there.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a number of deletions, but most threads and replies are still intact.

Change any URL forum.bitcoin.org/XXXX to bitcointalk.org/XXXXX or bitcoin.org/smf/XXXXX to bitcointalk.org/XXXXX

Answer (score 0):

It seems https://bitcointalk.org/ has the posts since November 22, 2009. For example, all satoshi's posts are [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=3;sa=showPosts) (user id u=3).

Regarding earlier posts, in [satoshi's first post in bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5.msg28#msg28) he refers to an "old forum":

```
Welcome to the new Bitcoin forum!

The old forum can still be reached here:
http://bitcoin.sourceforge.net/boards/index.php

I'll repost some selected threads here and add updated answers to questions where I can.

FAQ
http://bitcoin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?page=FAQ

Download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/
```

and some people wrote that it's here:
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=bitcoin-list